# jQuery with remote validation does not wait for answer from server

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-plugins, jquery-validate

I've noticed, that sometimes my validation code works wrong:

```
var $validator = $("#checkoutForm").validate();

...

if (!$validator.element($sameShippingAddress)) {
     ...       
}
```

Debugging with Firebug showed, that sometimes $validator.element($sameShippingAddress) would return undefined (I guess it just does not wait till response is returned) and that would be assumed as false, even if element is valid.

If add code like this before if statement, everything works fine:

```
 while (validator.element($sameShippingAddress) !== undefined) {

 }
```

Question is if that is right solution and there's no better way to handle problem with validation plugin itself?

Update: I'm using http://bassistance.de/jquery-plugins/jquery-plugin-validation/

Comment: I have been pulling my hair out on the same problem. Your question provides me with an interim solution (the `while` loop) but it would be nice to know if whether there is a better solution.

Answer (score 1):

Infinite while loop on validator variable is not a good choice. Instead use the code below that utilise Javascript timer. You can show animated processing/server response graphics after validate() method.

```
var validator = $('#resetpassword').validate({///your code...})

    doTimer();

    function timedCount()
    {
        t=setTimeout("timedCount()",1000);
    }

    function doTimer()
    {
    if (validator === undefined)
      {
        timedCount();
      }
    }

if(validator==true)
    $('#form').ajaxSubmit(options);
```

Answer (score 1):

It's hard to tell how you are handling successful submissions or if you uses the css class to denoted required fields, but the following is how it's done in the [demo](http://jquery.bassistance.de/validate/demo/) for the plugin:

```
$.validator.setDefaults({
    // code to be executed on submit
submitHandler: function() { alert("submitted, replace this with your server request");}
});

$().ready(function() {
    // validate the comment form when it is submitted
        // use css class .required for fields you want the validator to check
        // if your form is valid then it is handled by the submitHandler
        // if not the plugin displays error messages
    $("#checkoutForm").validate();
    //validate can take a block for custom validation and error messages
});
```

Hope this helps you find a solution and isn't just more of the same (also just realized this question is a year old, but I already wrote this so...)

Answer (score 0):

Obiously, it is not the best solution. Instead add

if (!$validator.element($sameShippingAddress)) {
     ...
}

in the Ajax callback function.

Comment: not sure if i understand what you're offering. I think i need to specify more exact what is what: element is http://docs.jquery.com/Plugins/Validation/Validator/element and remote validator is http://docs.jquery.com/Plugins/Validation/Methods/remote and remote validator configuration is generated by asp.net mvc.